# How to mix list comprehensions with non-comprehension items?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to build-up a list from some individual items as well as groups of items defined by list comprehensions. Suppose I want a list `['foo', 0, 2, 4, 'bar']`, where `0,2,4` would come from a comprehension. The only way I know of doing it is:

```
['foo'] + [x*2 for x in range(3)] + ['bar']
```

Is there a way of doing it without explicit appending? I'm looking for some clever equivalent to the following non-working desired syntax:

```
['foo', x*2 for x in range(3), 'bar'] # invalid syntax :(
```

My presumption is that perhaps a similar syntax would avoid the creation of all the intermediate temporary lists that then have to be copied element-by-element in order to append them to the list being built, when using the explicit `+` operator.

I'm looking for a solution that'd preferably be pythonic (idiomatic), for Python 2.7 and 3.x - should they be different.

The motivating code is below, where `ScreamingBOM` is a named tuple - I'm trying to build the tuple up while creating as few temporaries as possible, since some of them may get quite sizable.

```
def make_screaming_bom(self, bom):
    return ScreamingBOM(
        summary = [
            ['', '', 'generated on: %s' % bom.time],
            ['', bom.unique_parts, 'unique parts'],
            []
        ]
        + [['', count, 'total %s' % (type)] for type, count in bom.counts.items()]
        + [
            ['', bom.total, 'total placements'],
            [],
            ['BOM: %s' % (bom.title)],
            ['Assembly Part Number/Revision: %s / %s' % (bom.basename, bom.revision)],
            ['Customer: %s' % (bom.company)]
        ],
        # other tuple fields follow
    )
```

Answer (score 5):

Best you can get to avoid temporaries is using [generalized unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) with a generator expression:

```
['foo', *(x*2 for x in range(3)), 'bar']
```

On CPython 3.9, that compiles to code equivalent to making an empty list, `append`ing `'foo'`, `extend`ing with the genexpr, then `append`ing `'bar'`. The `extend` step consumes the generator without realizing it as a `list`, avoiding any temporaries. The code with a temporary `list` (see [bb1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66343655/364696)) is likely to be slightly faster, but if you're set on avoiding temporaries, this is the most memory efficient solution.

The Python 2 "solution" is you just make a `list` and manually `append` and `extend` line-by-line until you're done. If you really insist on one-liners no matter how ugly, using `itertools.chain` will allow something fairly similar to how generalized unpacking worked when it was first introduced through 3.8 (items not unpacked were wrapped in temporary `tuple`s, then a `list` was built by unpacking all the arguments passed):

```
list(itertools.chain(('foo',), (x*2 for x in range(3)), ('bar',)))
```

But Python 2 has been end-of-life for over a year, so just write modern Python 3 code. :-)

Comment: Similarly here, this will not work in Python 2.
In Python 2, I don't think there actually is a better way of doing this besides a series of `append` and `extend`.

Comment: @1313e: Yeah, Python 2 is dead, so I don't really care about it. Some ugly code with `itertools.chain` is possible there if they *really* insist, but it's awful, not worth the trouble.

Comment: I 100% agree that Python 2 is dead and should not be used. However, the OP specifically requested a solution for Python 2.7 and Python 3.x.

Comment: @1313e: I added the terrible Py2 solution, just for completeness. But I need you to understand the level of disdain I have for it, even if it technically satisfies the OP's needs. :-)

Comment: Agreed. I very much dislike Python 2.7 as well and the many ugly scripts that it requires.

Comment: In my particular use case, Python 2.7 is what comes with KiCad on Windows, but I'm hell bent on recompiling that monster myself just to get a binary with Python 3 included :) As far as dependency hells go, CAD systems are close to the top of the food chain :/

Answer (score 2):

How about list upacking?

```
['foo', *[x*2 for x in range(3)], 'bar']
```

Comment: This will not work in Python 2, but is the solution I would go with for Python 3.

Comment: While this is a good answer to OP's question, I think you should also mention how this is inefficient. I'm doing some testing right now, but I have a feeling using a generator instead of a list comprehension would be less of a memory hog.

Comment: @blorgon: The genexpr will use less memory; the listcomp will (often) be faster (genexprs have higher fixed overhead per item in my experience). If memory is likely to be an issue, the genexpr is safer (and the performance shouldn't be much worse), but if memory isn't an issue, the choice hardly matters.

Comment: Interesting. I expected exactly that to work, but tried only in 2.7 and it didn't work there :)

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica: Yeah, the additional unpacking generalizations from PEP 448 were only added in 3.5; any reasonably modern Py3 has them, but none were backported to Py2.